# Is there a way to check if query has completed?

Tags: for-loop, google-sheets, s

Is there a way to have an if statement wait for query to complete before finishing?

I have the following formula in google sheets cell C3.  In Cell B3 I have a search box.

```
=iferror(if($B$3="","",if(query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/edit#gid=1009875416","'Responses'!AD3:AL")," select Count(Col1) where lower(Col9) contains '"&lower(B3)&"' label count(Col1) ''",0)=1,"1 Result Found",query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/edit#gid=1009875416","' Responses'!AD3:AL")," select Count(Col1) where lower(Col9) contains '"&lower(B3)&"' label count(Col1) ''",0)&" Results Found")),"No Results Found")
```

When B3 is blank, all the results from the table Responses are there.  When I type in something to search in B3 and hit enter, the table emptys with no results there and in C3 it says No Results Found, and then a couple seconds later comes up with either 1 Result Found or X Results Found and populates the table.

The question is why does it show No Results Found at first, and then change?  The only thing I can think of is it runs before the query is finished, so wondering if there is a way to prevent the if from completing until the query completes.

Thanks
Doc

Answer (score 0):

1. Every time you change value in `B3` the spreadsheet has to refetch data. Even if there is some caching, it takes some seconds.  To avoid it, you could import all data in a separate sheet and feed it to `QUERY` functions in your formula, instead of using `IMPORTRANGE`.
2. It looks like you have an extra space in `"' Responses'!AD3:AL"` which makes the range invalid and probably triggers `IFERROR`'s fallback to "No Results Found".
3. Important: the sheet in the formula is publicly accessible which is usually not safe.  I do not know if it is intentional.  You can read more [security issues with access via a link here](https://dataful.tech/google-sheets/security/sharing-via-link/) (disclosure: it is my website).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The space is Responses was just a typo, in the file it is correct. I will just leave it as is, not really that big of a deal. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

So here is an update.  I found a solution.  I removed the iferror to see what was happening.  The "first" No Results Found was a "loading..." error.  The "second" No Results Found was an #N/A error.  So I changed the iferror to ifna and then wrapped the entire function in an iferror and gave it a value_if_error value of "Searching...".  So now, when I do a search, and it throws the "loading" error, it says Searching... and if it finds no results, it says No Results.

Here is the modified formula (and per dataful.tech, I changed the importrange values in this and original post to a "ID")

```
=iferror(ifna(if($B$3="","",if(query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/edit#gid=1009875416","'JGOOT Responses'!AD3:AL")," select Count(Col1) where lower(Col9) contains '"&lower(B3)&"' label count(Col1) ''",0)=1,"1 Result Found",query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/edit#gid=1009875416","'JGOOT Responses'!AD3:AL")," select Count(Col1) where lower(Col9) contains '"&lower(B3)&"' label count(Col1) ''",0)&" Results Found")),"No Results Found"),"Searching...")
```